# Is it possible to check all fonts are set as ‘embedded subset’ in pdf

Tags: shell, pdf

At time of converting source files to a PDF that make sure that all fonts are set as ‘embedded subset’

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got an answer that : 
 For subsetted fonts, the font name is preceded by 6 random characters and a plus sign.
We can check any other fonts that are not 'embedded subset'. For this we can use below code

pdffonts "file1.pdf" | awk '{print $1}' | grep -v + | sed 's/name//g' | sed 's/-//g'

The above code give the list of not embedded subset fonts.  This is useful for me.

Answer (score 2):

On linux, 'pdffonts file.pdf' will enumerate all referenced fonts

```
pdffonts file.pdf
+ pdffonts file.pdf
name                                 type              encoding         emb sub uni object ID
------------------------------------ ----------------- ---------------- --- --- --- ---------
WHZYWG+Times-Roman                   Type 1C           Custom           yes yes no       8  0
```

The embedded indicator ('emb') and the subset indicator ('sub') are available

Comment: i am also reach this function, I want to check in this result "emb", "sub" are yes  even if there are multiple font set,